# Is this bindValue wrong?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I have a `PDO statement` as follows(**AFAIK**, PDO doesn't need data to be `escaped` for preparation):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `errors`(`code`,`number`,`title`,`message`) VALUES( :code, :num, :title, :err )";
$arr = Array(
    Array( ':code', $_POST['code'], 'PDO::PARAM_STR' ),
    Array( ':num', $_POST['number'], 'PDO::PARAM_INT' ),
    Array( ':title', $_POST['title'], 'PDO::PARAM_STR' ),
    Array( ':err', htmlentities( str_replace("\n", "<br />", $_POST['error']), ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8' ), 'PDO::PARAM_STR' )
);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($insert);
foreach( $arr as $a ) {
    $stmt->bindValue( $a[0], $a[1], $a[2] );
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
```

This piece of code does nothing at all. But it does generate a dump like this:

```
SQL: [91] INSERT INTO `errors`(`code`,`number`,`title`,`message`) VALUES( :code, :num, :title, :err )
Params:  0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding four parameters?

Comment: @andrewsi There aren't four parameters.

Comment: I'm looking at the bindValue call, with `$a[0], $a[1], $a[2]` - should there be four there, or are you doing something clever with arrays?

Comment: @andrewsi Nothing fancy! Just started PDO. There are 3 parameters required of [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). You confused it with `bindParam()`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing. I clearly need more coffee!

Comment: Side note: you're over-optimizing your code; your array of parameters to bind does not add clarity, and if you do four straight calls to `bindValue` instead of a loop over the array, your code will get 69 chars shorter and (IMO) better-readable.

Comment: I was trying to pass the entire array in one statement, but that didn't seem to work, hence I switched on to this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type info of a bind parameter is a `constant`, and not a *string*:

```
Array( ':code', $_POST['code'], PDO::PARAM_STR )
//                             ^              ^ no quotes
```

**Update**

The array should look like this:

```
$arr = Array(
    Array( ':code', $_POST['code'], PDO::PARAM_STR ),
    Array( ':num', $_POST['number'], PDO::PARAM_INT ),
    Array( ':title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR ),
    Array( ':err', htmlentities( str_replace("\n", "<br />", $_POST['error']), ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8' ), PDO::PARAM_STR )
);
```

Comment: It means I'll have to have an `if` or `ternary` statement there?

Comment: Thanks. After putting `($a[0] == ":num")?PDO::PARAM_INT:PDO::PARAM_STR` instead of `$a[2]` it is not working. :)

Comment: no, a `constant`, from the manual: `Explicit data type for the parameter using the PDO::PARAM_* constants`